# Which is bigger $(n!)^m$ or $(m!)^n$?

Tags: inequality

Assume $m>n$, which is bigger $(m!)^n$ or  $(n!)^m$?

This question came about during a Taylor series approximation.

Considering [plot](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=plot%20%28n!%29%5E%281/n%29) of $(n!)^{1/n}$ and [Stirling's formula](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stirling%27s_approximation) one guesses larger base wins.

Comment: Which is bigger, $n$ or $m$?

Comment: Are there any restrictions on $m$ and $n$?

Comment: Write them in term of one variable, e.g. let $m=n+a$ where $a \geq 0$

Comment: The are positive integers. In the particular application $m=n+1$.

Comment: @Jean-Sébastien  text of question was corrected.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Repeated use of the fact $n!\leq n^n$ yields

$$n!\cdot n!\cdots n!\lt (n+1)^n\cdot (n+2)^n\cdots (n+i)^n$$ for any $i\gt 0$, where there are $i$ terms on the LHS. Then we have

$$(n!)^i\lt \Big( (n+1)\cdots(n+i)\Big)^n$$

or equivalently

$$(n!)^i\lt \left( \frac{(n+i)!}{n!}\right)^n.$$

Rearranging, this says

$$(n!)^{n+i}\lt (n+i)!^n$$

so if we know $m\gt n$ then $m=n+i$ for some $i\gt 0$, so this tells us finally that

$$(n!)^{m}\lt (m)!^n$$

Answer (score 15):

Consider $m = n+1$.  Then $(m!)^n > (n!)^m$.

*Proof:*

$$
\begin{eqnarray*}
  (m!)^n &=& ([n+1]!)^n \\
  &=& (n+1)^n \cdot (n!)^n \\
  &=& \frac{(n+1)^n}{ (n!) } (n!)^{n+1}\\
  &=& \frac{(n+1)^n}{ (n!) } (n!)^{m}\\
\end{eqnarray*}
$$
Now since $n+1 > k$ for all $k = 1, 2, \ldots, n$, It is clear that $\frac{(n+1)^n}{n!} > 1$, proving the result.

A simple induction then shows if $m > n$, then $(m!)^n > (n!)^m$ in general.